# Laravel 5.3 - Handling NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.3

Im using Laravel 5.3 and in trying to handle all common exceptions from `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` inside `render()`. I want to save a session var and check it in the controller myself.

For example: for `TokenMismatchException`, it works well like this:

```
if($excp_class == 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'){
return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('TokenError', 'CSRF');
}
```

However, for `NotFoundHttpException`, I cant seem to get Session save a value.

```
if(stristr($excp_class, 'NotFoundHttpException')!=false)
{
    //return redirect()->route('XYZRoute')->with('TokenError', 'NotFound'); //Also tried `withError`

    \Request::session()->put('TokenError', 'NotFound'); //not working
    \Request::session()->save();

    return back();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you getting a PHP exception? I don't think there is a `withError` method on a `RedirectResponse`. There IS a `withErrors` (plural) method that expects a validation result (MessageProvider), but that's not what you what here. I think simply `with('TokenError', 'NotFound')` is what you want.

Comment: `With` also doesnt work. Ive tried many ways to put session here btw.

Comment: You need to explain "doesn't work" then. Your original code looked like it would cause a PHP exception. Explain what happens, how you're trying to access the error... details.

Comment: ive updated it now. See again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laravel did not find the route (NotFoundHttpException), your request did not pass through the middleware \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession. 
Your request does not have session then.

If you want all your request have a session, you will have to add \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, in $middleware of your Kernel :

```
namespace App\Http;
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ];
...
}
```

I did not test that but I hope  it will work and help you.

Comment: Awesome man.. that makes sense and solved the issue as well.. Thanks

Comment: Great. This also solved the issue I had trying to redirect a NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php with a flashed error message to another page.